# How to change the web application load in a dektop view in vb.net

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a web application, say the URL is http://www.example.com. I need to create an .exe file in Windows and on click this file the web application (http://www.example.com) needs to load in desktop application.

I have created a Windows Forms Application and created a button with name "Open App". On click this button I have written the code like

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.example.com".ToString());
```

where `webBrowser1` is the name Webrowser object.

It runs the application properly but when I click the button it shows me the `error like http://www.example.com/js/jquery.js script error`.

How can I make the script also run here?

Also how can I load the web URL on desktop application when the time of application load itself. I mean not by clicking the link?

The actual error code is

> Object doesn't support property or method addlistner

If this is not the correct method for convert this web application to desktop application please suggest the better way for me

Comment: `webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.example.com".ToString());` is c#. Are you sure you are using vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure you are using `vb.net`, use this on button click:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com")
End Sub
```

To open the website when your application load, put the code in `Form_Load`
Example:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com")
End Sub
```